# ORA-01008 Not All Variables Bound on a simple query C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am having the hardest time trying to neutralize this oracle not all variables bound. I tried the usual suggestions I got from some Google searches, but nothing seemed to help.

Eventually, for testing purposes, I reduced my query and code to a simple

```
public override List<DiscountList> GetDiscountList(string name)
    {

        string cmdText = "select discount from users where name = :Name";

        DbParameters prms = new DbParameters(Ado.AdoTemplate.DbProvider);

        prms.AddWithValue("Name", name);

        List<DiscountList> list = Ado.AdoTemplate.QueryWithRowMapperDelegate<DiscountList>(CommandType.Text, cmdText,
        new RowMapperDelegate<DiscountList>((reader, rowNum) =>
        {
            DiscountList item = new DiscountList();
            item.Discount = reader.GetString(0, string.Empty);

            return item;
        })).ToList();

        return list;
    }
```

But I still receive the Oracle error, I even hardcoded the second parameter in AddWithValue to make sure it is not passing a null issue, but still the same error.

EDIT: To include whole function

Comment: What driver are you using?  ODP.net?

Comment: @Hambone, most likely not, because ODP.NET does not provide method `AddWithValue`

Comment: @Hambone I am using ADO.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a silly mistake by me and I forgot an important piece of code:

```
})).ToList();
```

should be

```
}),prms).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you are using `DbParameters` instead of `OracleParameter` like

```
command.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Name", name));
```

(OR)

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a bigger code snippet, it's hard to say if what you have done should work or not.  To cut to the chase, this should be a working example of what I believe you are trying to do.

Note that the `AddWithValue` is very convenient and will nearly always result in the proper datatype mapping.  If you really want to be iron-clad explicit, you can use the overload that specifies the datatype.  If you ever start passing weird datatypes like Blobs, this might become important.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select discount from users where name = :Name",
    conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", OracleDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = name;

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    object discount = reader.GetValue(0);
}

reader.Close();
```

Comment: Method `AddWithValue` might be convenient, however it is not available in Oracle classes. You can use them only for Microsoft providers but they are all deprecated and should not be used in new projects: [ODBC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [OLE DB Provider for Oracle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [.NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That is good to know; thank you.  I actually use DevArt dotConnect for Oracle (which does have this method) and didn't know ODP.net didn't.

Comment: @Hambone I have included the full function

Answer (score -2):

I think the query should be like this:

```
string cmdText = "select discount from users where name = @Name";
```

Comment: The `@` to invoke a parameter works on SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, Sybase and probably a host of others, but not Oracle.  Oracle uses the colon.